# Alt codes with PuTTY

Tags: putty, windows-8.1

I want to send the alt code <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>. It will produce this alt code: `§`

However PuTTY is not recognising any alt codes, including §. What do I do to get it to recognise the code?

Comment: So... you don't want to *send* it, do you? You actually want to send the *character* this produces in other editors? PuTTY likely captures raw keyboard input, as it should.

Comment: Yes you're correct I want to type it.